# How to replace the existing value with with the new one

Tags: java, servlets

if the first name already exists then I want to replace the value of NetWOrth for that particular person without repeating the old value.

I tried to do that while looping through the list but it's giving me a repeated entry.

```
List<Celebrity> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Celebrity>();

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    Celebrity cl = new Celebrity("Frank", "Sinatra", "franks.inatra@smoothjazz.com", 1000000.00);
    Celebrity c2 = new Celebrity("Michal", "Jackson", "king of pop@mtv.com", 1000000000.00);
    Celebrity c3 = new Celebrity("Aaron", "Hoffman", "jamsonreal@smoothjazz.com", 10000.00);

    list.add(cl);
    list.add(c2);
    list.add(c3);

    String firstName = request.getParameter("first");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("last");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    double netWorth = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("netWorth"));


    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) {
            list.get(i).setNetWorth(netWorth);
        }

        if (!list.get(i).getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) {
            list.add(new Celebrity(firstName, lastName, email, netWorth));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest do not use raw `List` use `List<Celebrity>` instead.

Comment: Sorry that was typo.. i am using  --------------------   List <Celebrity> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Celebrity>();

Comment: i am stuck in the condition part....

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand why u compare email with firstname:

```
 ...
        if (list.get(i).getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) {
         ...
```

and this might be a solution to your problem if i understood correctly:

```
  for(Celebrity  ce:list){
  if (ce.getFirstName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName.trim()) &&ce.getNetworth!=netWorth){
    ce.setNetworth(networth);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is very confusing but, it seems the "break" is not placed in the right location. If you want to update a property (uf, I don't like mutable objects but this is my opinion) and then stop the for just move the "break" to the first "if"

if (list.get(i).getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))